# where does the term $\frac{N(x)}{N(x)+N(y)}\left(\frac{x}{N(x)}\right)+\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)}\left(\frac{y}{N(y)}\right)$ come from?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

> Could somebody explain where does the term $\frac{N(x)}{N(x)+N(y)}\left(\frac{x}{N(x)}\right)+\frac{N(y)}{N(x)+N(y)}\left(\frac{y}{N(y)}\right)$ come from? I don't understand why it is used and how it is dervied exactly.

The rest of the proof is below:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b\in B$, where $B$ is convex then $ta + (1 - t)b \in B$ for any $0\leq t \leq 1$. Apply this with
$$
a = \frac{x}{{N(x)}},\;b = \frac{y}{{N(y)}},\;t = \frac{{N(x)}}{{N(x) + N(y)}}.
$$